# Is there a way to save pdf generated from html2pdf in specific path?

Tags: javascript, html2pdf

I am using html2pdf library to create a pdf and save it and i want to save it to specific folder how can i do that can you guys please assit me?

````
function generatePDF(){
    // Choose the element that our invoice is rendered in.
    const element = document.getElementById('bill');
    // Choose the element and save the PDF for our user.
    html2pdf().from(element).save();
}```
````

Comment: No you can not.

Comment: why it cannot can you tell me the reason please?

Comment: Because the browser will not allow you to save it in a specific path, only on the default download folder

Comment: ok then am i able give save as option? is it possible

Comment: Just out of curiosity I would try if he `.save()` function is made to receive params.:  `html2pdf().from(element).save( [ path ], [ boolean ] );`

Comment: https://ekoopmans.github.io/html2pdf.js/ acutaly it doesnt anyway thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem working on Nextjs if someone needs help with it my solution will save a pdf in a specific folder for me 'pdfs' in the root folder:

Client Side:

```
const generatePDF = async () => {
  const apiUrl =
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL || "http://localhost:3000/api";
  const content = document.getElementById("pdf-content");

  if (content) {
    try {
      const { default: html2pdf } = await import("html2pdf.js");

      const pdfBlob = await html2pdf(content).outputPdf();
      const arrayBuffer = await new Response(pdfBlob).arrayBuffer();
      const base64String = btoa(new TextDecoder().decode(arrayBuffer));

      const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/pdf/save-pdf`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ pdfBase64: base64String, emailAddress: sessionStorage.getItem('email') }),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        console.log("PDF saved successfully on the server!");
      } else {
        console.error("Failed to save the PDF on the server");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error while generating or saving the PDF:", error);
    }
  }
};
```

My server side function:

```
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: 
 NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const { pdfBase64, emailAddress } = req.body;

try {
  // Convert the base64 string to ArrayBuffer
  const buffer = Buffer.from(pdfBase64, "base64").buffer;

  // Save the ArrayBuffer as PDF in the /pdfs directory
  const fs = await import("fs/promises");
  const path = await import("path");

  const pdfPath = path.join(process.cwd(), "pdfs", `Commande-${Date.now()}.pdf`);
  await fs.writeFile(pdfPath, Buffer.from(buffer));

  // Send email with attachment
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: '',
    port: ,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'your email',
        pass: 'password',
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
    from: 'your email',
});

  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'your email',
    to: emailAddress, 
    subject: "Commande PDF",
    text: "Please find the attached PDF.",
    attachments: [
      {
        filename: `Commande-${Date.now()}.pdf`,
        path: pdfPath,
      },
    ],
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error("Error sending email:", error);
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Error sending email", error });
    } else {
      console.log("Email sent:", info.response);
      res.status(200).json({ message: "PDF saved and email sent successfully" });
    }
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error saving the PDF on the server:", error);
  res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
}
} else {
  res.status(405).json({ message: "Method Not Allowed" });
}
```

}